# Is it possible to programmatically retrieve the Sharepoint contact lists that a user has added to their outlook?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007, sharepoint-api, outlook-2010

I have a custom addressbook built into a c#.net app.  My users have gone into Sharepoint and have connected/linked the contact list there into their outlook.  They would like for these Sharepoint Contact lists to show up in our custom addressbook app, but I can't find a way to access that particular data.

I was hoping that there would be some LDAP path or EWS call that I could make to get these Sharepoint contact lists.

I've thought about looking at sharepoint directly via the API to get the contact list data, but I still wouldn't know if they have actually added those lists to their outlook or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration of a SharePoint connection is stored in the folder asssociated items table of the inbox folder. See http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/13/Enumerating-Sharepoint-Connections-in-a-mailbox-with-EWS.aspx for a sample on how to enumerate them.

Comment: well what doesn't make sense to me is that why in Outlook 2010 if i open up outlook on a different machine it will automatically have those sharepoint lists added (if i set the roaming option).  That's hwy i figured the sharepoint lists were being saved somewhere in exchange.  Do you think that outlook is communicating directly with sharepoint when it boots up and the only optino that is being savedo n the exchange server is the option to check sharepoint or not for new lists?